# foreignObject in svg not position correctly when text overflow in chrome

Tags: svg, scroll, position, overflow

The div inside foreignObject moves out of the foreignObject when the height of the div is larger than the foreignObject's height. I am unable to position the div correctly. Anyone have a solution or experiencing the same issue?

This situation only happens on the macbook's display but is working fine if I place the browser in a dual monitor display.

I am using google chrome Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit).
I am also using apple macbook pro 15 inch version 10.13.3 macos highsierra.

[Image - Macbook default monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqfKD.png)
[Image - Macbook using Dell's monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6PxI.png)

```css
svg {
   border: 1px solid black;
}          
foreignObject {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   transform: translate(50px, 50px);
}
div {
   border: 1px solid red;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<svg height='500px' width='500px'>
      <foreignObject height='100px' width='100px'>
         <div  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            Bacon ipsum dolor amet ball tip burgdoggen t-bone pastrami, ground
         </div>
      </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example to your question?

Comment: @hlg Thanks for the quick response. I just added a code example. If you delete the word 'ground' in the div then it is positioned correctly inside the foreignObject.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue with Chrome Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10. If it is a MacOS specific issue, I still can not imagine how a different display should affect the browser rendering. Maybe compare with hardware acceleration switched on and off?

Comment: @hlg, I tried turning the hardware acceleration off and the problem still persists. I have added two images of how it looks on two different monitors using the same macbook.